# Put content of a list item to bottom in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem about putting content of a list item to bottom, baseline.

take a look at this :

```
    <ul>
    <li class="box">
        <div class="close" ></div>
        <div class="head"> Header </div>
        <p class="area">
            This is Paragraph
        </p>
    </li>
    <li class="box">
        <div class="close" ></div>
        <div class="head"> Header </div>
        <p class="area">
            This is Paragraph
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the JQUERY part:

```
    $( document ).on( "click", "ul li .head", function() {

    $(this).parent('li').toggleClass( 'minimize' );
    $(this).parent('li').children('p').toggle();

});
```

AND finaly the CSS

```
ul { position: static; bottom: -4px; width: 1150px;  min-height: 250px; overflow:     hidden; 
}
ul li {
position: relative;
border: 1px solid lightgray;
width: 260px;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 2px;
}
ul li .head {
font-weight: bold;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #6D84B4;
color: white;
border: 1px solid #6D84B4;
text-align: right;
}
p.area { padding: 8px; height: 200px; }
.minimize { vertical-align: bottom;}
```

**Here is the jsFiddle link:**

[link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8GrtN/2/)

**Description**
When I click on only one header, the Paragraph hides and header goes bottom. ( OK )
But when I click the other header, both of them jumps to top again.

any help about this.
Thanks.

---

**EDITED & SOLVED:**
Well , I hoped somebody could help me to solve this in css way.
But I made a trick using jQuery. it is working. but I don't know it's a good way or not.

Here is the code:
[Updated Code](http://jsfiddle.net/8GrtN/64/)

Comment: it is because of the height of the `li` is reduced when both the elements are collapsed

Comment: do you have a fixed height for the `li` elements....

Comment: The question is: the bottom of what? Do you have some reserved space? The only thing that "pushes" the header "down" is the other block. When the other block is reduced there is no content up top to make everything "go down"

Comment: yes I know the reason why the other one goes down or both jumps to top, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The `bottom` property has no effect whatsoever on unpositioned elements.

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Vp6Lq/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with vertical-align is that it aligns the element with its `inline` adjacent siblings. When they are both minimized because they are the same height they appear inline with each other.

I would recommend using `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` of the fixed height `ul` although that will need a couple of tweaks to your current styling.

EDIT:

How about putting the ul in a container div, and absolute positioning the ul to the bottom of that.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/HeyDanReeves/pen/CBlAd)

The only difference is a div around the ul and I changed the following style:

```
.container { 
  position: relative;
  width: 1150px;  
  min-height: 282px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: with using position: absolute, I fully lose sibling functionality and that's not a good solution.

Comment: @aliA Edited the answer in line with your comment

Comment: Man I made this two days ago with position: absolute; BUT the problem is, When you hide one of these list items, you should consider the position of all list items after it. and also when addding. cuz they should stand beside each other.  Thank you. but absolute positioning brings more difficulty to me later.

Comment: @aliA In my second solution the list items are positioned relatively.

Comment: Awesome, works very well, but overflow:hidden doesn't work. lemme check it.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to ul

```
ul { position: static; bottom: -4px; width: 1150px;  min-height: 250px; overflow:     hidden; 
white-space: nowrap;}
```

Hope it works. :) I tried this code by deleting the new jQuery part in updated code and adding this.